# Saving a variant with new stock from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, stock

Has anyone had any luck trying to save a variant via a plugin?

I'm trying to integrate with a 3rd party inventory system and want to grab the current stock information and update my variants. Currently I have

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Commerce_Variant');
$criteria->sku = $sku;
$variant = $criteria->first();
```

Which works just fine to grab the variant i need, but...

```
$variant->stock = 99;
craft()->commerce_variants->saveVariant($variant);
```

This gives me no error, but does not update the variant in the database. What is the method I should be using to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, but as a rule I try an mimic what Commerce actually does itself.  In this area I would be inclined to follow the code Commerce uses in it's own completed order handling, found in `public function orderCompleteHandler` in `commerce/services/Commerce_VariantsService.php` around line 290:

```
        $purchasable = $lineItem->getPurchasable();

        // Only reduce variant stock if the variant exists in db
        if (!$purchasable)
        {
            continue;
        }

        $clearCacheOfElementIds = [];
        if ($purchasable instanceof Commerce_VariantModel && !$purchasable->unlimitedStock)
        {

            // Update the qty in the db
            craft()->db->createCommand()->update('commerce_variants',
                ['stock' => new \CDbExpression('stock - :qty', [':qty' => $lineItem->qty])],
                'id = :variantId',
                [':variantId' => $purchasable->id]);

            // Update the stock
            $purchasable->stock = craft()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('stock')
                ->from('commerce_variants')
                ->where('id = :variantId', [':variantId' => $purchasable->id])
                ->queryScalar();

            // Clear the cache since the stock changed
            $clearCacheOfElementIds[] = $purchasable->id;
            $clearCacheOfElementIds[] = $purchasable->product->id;
        }

        $clearCacheOfElementIds = array_unique($clearCacheOfElementIds);
        craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByElementId($clearCacheOfElementIds);
```